# WOW.js does not support for chrome 68.0.3440.106

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, wow.js

I used wow.js and animate.css in my project. I added wow attribute such as 'data-wow-delay="2s". However, it works in IE but not in Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106.
Actually, the animation part works but wow-delay does not happen. Is this a bug in WOW? Is there similar kind of Javascript libraries available which works for the most browser?

Comment: can you please post the most minimal bit of code required for others to replicate this? Without the code it's impossible to say what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

my App.js is as follws.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import WOW from 'wowjs/dist/wow.js';
import './Animate.css';
import './App.css';
import {
  Route,
  withRouter,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    new WOW.WOW().init();
  }
  
      return (
        <Layout className="app-container">
          <AppHeader isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
            currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
            onLogout={this.handleLogout} />

              <Content className="app-content">
              <div className="middle-content">
                    <div className="description col-3 wow bounceIn animated" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="1s"><h1>WE OFFER 100%</h1><h3>MONEY BACK GUARANTEE</h3>
                    <p>on all our quality products with hassle - free returns.
                    We believe you will be completely satisfied with your purchase.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="app-content-img fadeInRight animated">
                      <img src={require("./3.png")} />
                    </div>
              </div>
```

It only works in IE.